# C# How to convert a parent’s hwnd (IntPtr) into NativeWindow that can be used in a Form.Show(nativewindow)

Tags: c#, forms, credential-providers, nativewindow

I'm trying to show a dialog over my Credential Provider tile. I call the `OnCreatingWindow()` method (from `CredentialProvider.Interop.dll`) which returns the HWND of the appropriate parent window. Before beeing able to use the handle in Form.Show(parentWindow), I need to convert the HWND handle into a NativeWindow implementing IWin32Window. This conversion does not work for me.

I've tried (where parentWndHandle is returned from OnCreatingWindow())

```
var nativeWindow = new NativeWindow();
nativeWindow.AssignHandle(parentWndHandle);
```

and

```
IWin32Window parent = NativeWindow.FromHandle(parentWndHandle);
```

and

```
IWin32Window parent = Control.FromHandle(parentWndHandle)
```

All of them return null

Expected result should be a NativeWindow to parent the dialog I want to show

Comment: Did you find an answer to this ?